# Apache Superset Table Export To Excel

Tags: apache-superset

There is an option in Apache Superset to export the table data into csv but the problem is that only selected data is able to export which is available on the page if pagination is applied in the table.

Multiple csv files are downloaded if more than one query will get involved to fetch the data.

Is there any way to export the whole table data into a single excel or csv?